# Is there a way to change the value of [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] to

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

to undetermined again.

When the value is undetermined, iOS will ask what to do.

Well, if the status is already rejected, iOS won't ask again.

I want iOs to ask again.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in code. If your status is rejected, simply tell the user that he should start Settings.app and enable access for your application.